# Can not instantiate java class in JSF

Tags: java, jsf

I want to learn JSF and after reading and watching some tutorials I decided to give it a try and build a very simple Hello World example. Unfortunately the server can not instantiate the java class. The example is so simple that I am not sure if there is actually a problem with the code or if I have screwed up at setting up the project.

I am using a apache-tomcat-9.0.17 server and this is all the relevant code.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

index.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
<h:head>
    <title>Hello World - Input Form</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="myresponse" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

myresponse.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Hello World - Response</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h4>Hello, #{helloWorld.name}</h4>
</h:body>
</html>
```

HelloWorld.java

```
package JSF_Test;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
@ManagedBean(name = "helloWorld")
@RequestScoped
public class HelloWorld{

private String name = "Tom";

public HelloWorld(){

    }



public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Programm console output(no problem)

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\patri\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JSFTestApp 
Dnb.internal.action.name=run -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true 
DforceRedeploy=false 
Dbrowser.context=C:\\Users\\patri\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JSFTestApp
run
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
Starting Tomcat process...
Waiting for Tomcat...
Tomcat server started.
Incrementally deploying http://localhost:8080/JSFTestApp
Completed incremental distribution of http://localhost:8080/JSFTestApp
Incrementally redeploying http://localhost:8080/JSFTestApp
Start is in progress...
start?path=/JSFTestApp
OK - Anwendung mit Kontext Pfad [/JSFTestApp] gestartet
run-deploy:
Browsing: http://localhost:8080/JSFTestApp
run-display-browser:
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)
```

Server console output (errors)

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat
9.0.17\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17\bin\tomcat
juli.jar"
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.203 INFO [main]
org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 
Server Version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.17
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.207 INFO [main]
org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:
Mar 13 2019 15:55:27 UTC

06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.208 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 9.0.17.0
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.208 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.208 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.208 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architektur:          amd64
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.208 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.208 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           11.0.2+9-LTS
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.209 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Hersteller:            Oracle Corporation
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.209 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log 
 CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.209 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.209 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.210 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.210 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.210 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17\conf\logging.properties
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.210 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.210 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|DESKTOP-B8VLDNL
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.210 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.210 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.210 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.211 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.211 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.211 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17\temp
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.211 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.21] using APR version [1.6.5].
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.211 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.211 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.225 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018]
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.274 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initialisiere ProtocolHandler["http-nio-8080"]
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.342 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initialisiere ProtocolHandler["ajp-nio-8009"]
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.347 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [582] milliseconds
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.412 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.412 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.17]
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.423 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17\conf\Catalina\localhost\JSFTestApp.xml]
06-Apr-2019 12:48:22.446 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor The path attribute with value [/JSFTestApp] in deployment descriptor [C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17\conf\Catalina\localhost\JSFTestApp.xml] has been ignored
06-Apr-2019 12:48:23.478 INFO [main] com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) fÃ¼r Kontext '/JSFTestApp' wird initialisiert.
06-Apr-2019 12:48:23.624 INFO [main] com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory.createInstance JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy-Annotationen vorhanden.  Verwaltete Bean-Methoden, die mit diesen Annotationen markiert sind, lassen die entsprechenden Annotationen verarbeiten.
06-Apr-2019 12:48:24.188 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17\conf\Catalina\localhost\JSFTestApp.xml] has finished in [1.766] ms
06-Apr-2019 12:48:24.189 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploye Web-Applikations-Verzeichnis [C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17\webapps\docs]
06-Apr-2019 12:48:24.215 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17\webapps\docs] has finished in [26] ms
06-Apr-2019 12:48:24.215 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploye Web-Applikations-Verzeichnis [C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17\webapps\examples]
06-Apr-2019 12:48:25.262 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17\webapps\examples] has finished in [1.047] ms
06-Apr-2019 12:48:25.262 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploye Web-Applikations-Verzeichnis [C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17\webapps\host-manager]
06-Apr-2019 12:48:25.311 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [49] ms
06-Apr-2019 12:48:25.312 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploye Web-Applikations-Verzeichnis [C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17\webapps\manager]
06-Apr-2019 12:48:25.356 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17\webapps\manager] has finished in [44] ms
06-Apr-2019 12:48:25.356 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploye Web-Applikations-Verzeichnis [C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17\webapps\ROOT]
06-Apr-2019 12:48:25.387 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\patri\apache-tomcat-9.0.17\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [31] ms
06-Apr-2019 12:48:25.391 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
06-Apr-2019 12:48:25.402 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
06-Apr-2019 12:48:25.408 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [3.060] milliseconds
06-Apr-2019 12:48:28.624 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-3] com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) fÃ¼r Kontext '/JSFTestApp' wird initialisiert.
06-Apr-2019 12:48:28.709 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-3] com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory.createInstance JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy-Annotationen vorhanden.  Verwaltete Bean-Methoden, die mit diesen Annotationen markiert sind, lassen die entsprechenden Annotationen verarbeiten.
06-Apr-2019 12:48:31.489 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-7] com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.handleRenderException Error Rendering View[/myresponse.xhtml]
 javax.el.ELException: /myresponse.xhtml: Klasse JSF_Test.HelloWorld kann nicht instanziiert werden.
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:90)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Klasse JSF_Test.HelloWorld kann nicht instanziiert werden.
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:191)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:94)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:137)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:238)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:154)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    at JSF_Test.HelloWorld.<init>(HelloWorld.java:1)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
    ... 45 more

06-Apr-2019 12:48:31.663 1100 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.log JSF1073: javax.el.ELException erfasst wÃ¤hrend Verarbeitung von RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=/myresponse.xhtml: Klasse JSF_Test.HelloWorld kann nicht instanziiert werden.
06-Apr-2019 12:48:31.663 1100 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.log /myresponse.xhtml: Klasse JSF_Test.HelloWorld kann nicht instanziiert werden.
 javax.el.ELException: /myresponse.xhtml: Klasse JSF_Test.HelloWorld kann nicht instanziiert werden.
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:90)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Klasse JSF_Test.HelloWorld kann nicht instanziiert werden.
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:191)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:94)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:137)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText(ELText.java:238)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText(ELText.java:154)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write(TextInstruction.java:85)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    at JSF_Test.HelloWorld.<init>(HelloWorld.java:1)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: Sure this is all there is in your java HelloWorld class? Normally, in plain java, this happens when the constructor throws a runtime error (as a searchengine would tell you)

Comment: Yes, that is all. I will set up a Glassfish server tomorrow and report if that was the problem.

Comment: Strange... please do. Oh and if you are starting new with JSF, use 2.3 and use a modern 2.3 tutorial. Lots of old jsf things in your code that are deprecated! E.g. switch to CDI for bean management and use all JSF 2.2 and up namespaces and more generic, package names are normally lowercase in java